# I am trying to copy from one column to another in same table but getting msg 50000 and error 3609 as well

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
UPDATE poitem_mst
SET Uf_TYRI_poitem_req_ship_date=promise_date
```

Should be simple, but I get these errors:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RaiseErrorSp, Line 121 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Purchase Order that has [PO: P000010685] does not exist.
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

The PO number changes every time I run that query.

Comment: You have a trigger.  The code is much more complicated than you think.

Comment: I literally just want to copy from one column to another column in the same table. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: . . Your code is fine.  The table has a trigger that is broken.

Comment: Do you think I could just disable those triggers that are in that table temporarily and then run the query? Or would that break something else?